# call JavaScript function inside razor foreach statement

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have looked through several posts but have not found an answer that actually solves this issue so I am asking whilst trying to provide the most pertinent details.

I have a very simple script file called custom.js ...

```
function AddListItemToUnorderedList(pageCode, menuName) {
    $('.child_nav').append('<li><a href="' + pageCode + '"><span>' + menuName + '</span></a></li>');
}
```

I have made reference to that script in my partial page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/custom.js"></script>

@{
   Layout = null;
 }

 <ul class="child_nav" style="display: none;"></ul>

 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.MenuItems)
 {
     @Html.Raw("<script type='text/javascript'>")
     @Html.Raw("AddListItemToUnorderedList('")
     @item.PageCode
     @Html.Raw("', '")
     @item.MenuName
     @Html.Raw("');")
     @Html.Raw("</script>")
 }
```

The above code works but it looks terrible AND it adds a **script** tag to the markup for each item in the MenuItems collection. The MenuItems collection simply contains a list of two strings correlating to my menu's display name and html link....consider this to be populated with something as simple as **Test Page** for the name and **myTestPage.com** for the link.

I have see some shortcut syntax like this

```
@: AddListItemToUnorderedList(item.PageCode, item.MenuName)
```

however, I am not able to get that to work no matter what I try.

Any clear suggestions that work that will allow me to make a direct call to the JavaScript function passing in the two properties from the ViewBag where I don't have to create the **script** tags and use @Html.Raw?

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, put the values in `data-*` attributes & read them from JS.

Comment: I would appreciate a solution to the above question, not a re-engineer

Comment: Not sure what's "not a re-engineer", but I'd suggest passing the entire `MenuItems` object as json into a JS function and doing the iteration there, (if you don't want razor creating the elements themselves as SLaks suggests)

Comment: You don't need to put the `script` tags inside the `foreach`; just put the opening tag before and the closing tag after. As long as everything within your `foreach` is writing JavaScript code, that should be sufficient.

Comment: Why does it have to use `Html.Raw`? Also, you'll have to have `script` tags if you want to run script...

Comment: Mike, I tried adding the script tag outside the loop and this didn't get me the results.  The code provided works but it isn't as efficient as I would like.  Was hoping someone would know a working shortcut syntax like the @: or similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the below should work.  Pull out the script tags from the foreach, and then reference the javascript.  You'll also have to put `<text></text>` tags around the javascript and quotes around the variables so they will transfer correctly:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MenuItems)
{
    <text>AddListItemToUnorderedList('@item.PageCode', '@item.MenuName')</text>
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code won't work; the contents of a block (such as `@foreach`) is C#, not HTML.

Comment: Slaks, my code DOES work but I know there has to be a better way

Comment: eric g, so when I add the script tab just before and after the foreach I am getting nothing back.  It does not work.  The error says a script cannot be nested inside an element, namely the ul.

Comment: @BrianEvans Can you put a console.log in there and see if that returns?  Also you could put on inside of the function and see if it is getting called with invalid data.  I use that same method in my code and it works.

Comment: @BrianEvans I just updated my answer with the correct formatting.  This exact example is running in my project as we speak and firing the JavaScript function correctly with only one script tag.

Comment: I was able to get your text syntax to work so my code looks much better but I still had to put the script tags inside with @Html.Raw.  So it works but putting the script tags outside the foreach loop is a syntax problem because of the unordered list.

Comment: @BrianEvans yes, that is true.  Since you are using jquery to append to the ul tag the foreach loop doesn't actually need to exist inside the ul.  You could move that anywhere you want so avoid the syntax error and it would still append in the appropriate place.